# fscanf overwriting next bytes in memory (C)

Tags: c, memory, malloc, overwrite, scanf

The basic gist is, I'm reading words from a text file, storing them as a string, running a function, and then looping over this multiple times, rewriting that string with every new line read. After this loop is done, I need to deal with a different string. The problem is, the second string's bytes, even though I've memset them to 0 at declaration, are getting overwritten by the extra letters in words longer than the space I've allocated to the first string:

```
char* currDictWord = malloc(9*(sizeof(char));
char* currBrutWord = malloc(9*(sizeof(char));
memset(currBrutWord, 0, 9);
memset(currDictWord, 0, 9);

...

while (stuff) {

fscanf(dictionary, "%s", currDictWord);

}

...

printf("word: %s\n", currBrutWord);
```

currBrutWord will not be empty anymore. The two ways I've dealt with this are by either making sure currDictWord is longer than the longest word in the dictionary file (kind of a ghetto solution), and doing a new memset on currBrutWord after the loop. Is there no way to tell C to stop writing stuff into memory I've specifically allocated for a different variable?

Comment: Allocate much more space? Use a more sensible function than `fscanf`? Just write code that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: stop using `fscanf` (and preferably the whole `scanf`-family), and use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) instead, it lets you pass the maximum number of bytes to read into the variable.

**EDIT**: (in response to the comment)

`fgets` will stop reading until `count` bytes have been read or a newline has been found, which will be in the string. So after `fgets`ing the string check if there is a newline at the end of it (and remove if necessary). If there is no newline in the string `fgetc` from the file until you've found one, like this:

```
fgets(currDictWord, 9, dictionary);
if(currDictWord[strlen(currDictWord) - 1] != '\n'){
    while(fgetc(dictionary) != '\n'); /* no body necssary */
    /* the stream-pointer is now a the beginning of the next line */
}
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, because it continues reading the current line after 9 characters. i want it to throw away the rest of the line after 9 characters, instead of starting right where it left off. in addition, i've got some kind of bug where it's not even hitting the right string.

        fgets(currDictWord, 9, dictionary);

Comment: thank you! i ended up discovering that the problem with not taking the correct string had to do with the string including an invisible \n at the end, so i had to replace that with \0 as well, but your code provided the structure for that.

Comment: You're very welcome, don't forget to 'accept' the answer if it solves the question!

Answer (score 0):

**Improper string assignment and that not validating data read from a file.**

`currBrutWord` is overrun because too many `chars` were written into `currBrutWord`.  The same would have happened had you done:

```
strcpy(currBrutWord, "123456789");  // Bad as this copy 9+1 char into currBrutWord
```

When using `fscanf()`, one could limit the data read via:

```
fscanf(dictionary, "%8s", currDictWord);
```

This *prevents* `fscanf()` from putting too much data into `currDictWord`.  That part is good, but you still have unexpected data coming from the file.  You need to challenge any data from the *outside* world.

```
if (NULL == fgets(bigbuf, sizeof bigbuf, dictionary)) {
  ; handle EOF or I/O error
}
// now parse and validate bigbuf using various tools: strtok(), sscanf(), etc.
int n;
if ((sscanf(bigbuf, "%8s%n", currDictWord, &n) < 1) || (bigbif[n] != '\n')) {
  ; handle error
}
```